# pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-files

I am trying to read a data file using pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = "/home/gopakumar/Downloads/test.DAT"
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=';', engine='python',encoding="windows-1252")
```

and getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 468, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1057, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2496, in read
    alldata = self._rows_to_cols(content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 3189, in _rows_to_cols
    self._alert_malformed(msg, row_num + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2948, in _alert_malformed
    raise ParserError(msg)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 5 fields in line 3, saw 6
```

From the error description, I understand that the file has a different number of columns in each row, but this is how the file is, and is there any way to read such a file with a different number of columns in each row.

Following is a sample file:

```
0050;V2019.8.0.0;V2019.8.0.0;20200407;184821
0070;;7;0;7
0080;11;50;Abcd.pdf;Abcd;C:\Daten\Ablage\
0090;1;H;Holz;0;0;0;Holz;;;Holz
0090;1;Z;Abcdör;0;0;0;Abcd;;;Abcd
0090;1;N;Abcd;0;0;0;Abcd;;;Abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `header = None` all rows must have same no of cols like below:

```
data = """
0050;V2019.8.0.0;V2019.8.0.0;20200407;184821;;;;;;;;;;;
0070;;7;0;7
0080;11;50;Abcd.pdf;Abcd;C:\Daten\Ablage\
0090;1;H;Holz;0;0;0;Holz;;;Holz
0090;1;Z;Abcdör;0;0;0;Abcd;;;Abcd
0090;1;N;Abcd;0;0;0;Abcd;;;Abcd
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None, sep=';')
```

Output:

```
   0            1            2         3       4                    5    6     7     8    9     10   11    12  13  14    15
0  50  V2019.8.0.0  V2019.8.0.0  20200407  184821                  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN
1  70          NaN            7         0       7                  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN
2  80           11           50  Abcd.pdf    Abcd  C:\Daten\Ablage0090  1.0     H  Holz  0.0     0  0.0  Holz NaN NaN  Holz
3  90            1            Z    Abcdör       0                    0  0.0  Abcd   NaN  NaN  Abcd  NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN
4  90            1            N      Abcd       0                    0  0.0  Abcd   NaN  NaN  Abcd  NaN   NaN NaN NaN   NaN
```

Or if you know how many columns are there in the data you can also use:

```
cols = [f'col_{i}' for i in range(0,16)]
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=cols, sep=';')
```

Output:

```
   col_0        col_1        col_2     col_3   col_4                col_5  col_6 col_7 col_8  col_9 col_10  col_11 col_12  col_13  col_14 col_15
0     50  V2019.8.0.0  V2019.8.0.0  20200407  184821                  NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
1     70          NaN            7         0       7                  NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
2     80           11           50  Abcd.pdf    Abcd  C:\Daten\Ablage0090    1.0     H  Holz    0.0      0     0.0   Holz     NaN     NaN   Holz
3     90            1            Z    Abcdör       0                    0    0.0  Abcd   NaN    NaN   Abcd     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
4     90            1            N      Abcd       0                    0    0.0  Abcd   NaN    NaN   Abcd     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN
```